# Is there a standard way to specify that a node.js app is in production mode (or develop mode)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm asking for a standarized way. Something is commonly adopted.

Comment: just as far as practice goes, it tends to be the environment variable of `NODE_ENV`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard, but you *can* do this:

`$ export NODE_ENV=production`

I think this is only really necessary for express.js and preventing devDependencies from getting installed when running `npm i`.

Comment: Thanks for the "express" aclaration

Answer (score 4):

It's not "standardized," but it's almost universally adopted:

Set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to `production` (or `test` or `development` or whathaveyou).

You can, of course, access environment variables using `process.env`, e.g.:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  console.log('Some debug message...');
}
```